# How to make Shared Folders between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8, minecraft

I have managed to successfully dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8.1. I also play the very popular computer game called "Minecraft" and would like to be able to share the world files across both OSes.

I know it's kind of confusing and if you need more clarification I will be happy to provide it :)

*Is there any way to make the two Operating Systems share the same world files?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ln -s (insertwindowsminecraftfolderhere) ~/` in Terminal should allow you to do this (You may need to delete `~/.minecraft` in order for this to work (BACKUP YOUR DATA!))

Remember to replace `(insertwindowsminecraftfolderhere)` with the folder of your Windows hard drive's `.minecraft` folder! (i.e. if my Windows partition was mounted on `/mnt/sda1` and my `.minecraft` folder was located at `C:\Users\GrammarGeek\Appdata\LocalLow\Roaming\.minecraft` I'd run `ln -s /mnt/sda1/Users/GrammarGeek/Appdata/LocalLow/Roaming/.minecraft ~`)

Comment: Hey Thanks! I will make sure to try this and I just got Ubuntu 14.04 so I do not have any progress on it yet anyway but I will still back up ;)

Comment: OK @Grammargeek I ran the command and everything seemed to work fine but when I started up minecraft the world file was not there. Pretty much what I would like to happen is that they both will have the same world files, and I would be able to play on them without me having to continually copy and paste the contents of the world into .minecraft's 'saves' folder. I don't think I was that clear on what I wanted to do in my question so it's not your fault ;)

Comment: I understood what you were asking I personally play that game myself. What happens when you run `ls ~/.minecraft` in Terminal?

Comment: I get all of the contents of my ~/.minecraft folder, 'assets              launcher_profiles.json  options.txt    versions
launcher.jar        libraries               resourcepacks
launcher.pack.lzma  logs                    saves'

Comment: and if I do ~/.minecraft/saves, it returns nothing, because for some reason It isn't showing the Windows minecraft world as I would like it to. Do you think I should restart Ubuntu for it to do this?

Comment: @boatofturtles if you look at your Windows partition directly is there anything in `.minecraft/saves`?

Comment: No all of my world files are there :/ by the look of the command it looks like it should be successful

Comment: Weird... Can you give the output of `ls -l ~ | grep .minecraft`?

Comment: try renaming your `.minecraft` folder to `.minecraft.OLD` and running the command again

Comment: OK the output of the ls -l ~ | grep .minecraft command you gave me was nothing, it just returned to the next line. Ok I ran the ln -s command again and this time it returned: 'ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/jonah/.minecraft.OLD/.minecraft’: File exists' I checked my ~/.minecraft.OLD folder and no such file named .minecraft is there.

Comment: @boatofturtles I understand now run the new command (ln -s (winminecraftfolder) ~)

Comment: yes! I figured out the problem somehow the .minecraft.old got renamed back to .minecraft so what I did was moved the .minecraft.old to my desktop and then ran the command and success! Thanks! :)

Comment: @boatofturtles No idea what you where saying but, I'm really glad I could help :)